# Where am I going wrong in finding $\tan10^{\circ}$ form $\tan30^{\circ}$ using $\tan3A$ formula?

Tags: trigonometry

I tried finding $\tan10^{\circ}$ from $\tan30^{\circ}$ by using this method-

> $$\tan30^{\circ}=\tan3\times10^{\circ}=\frac{3\tan10^{\circ}-\tan^310}{1-3\tan^210^{\circ}}=\frac{1}{\sqrt3}$$

So,this is a cubic equation in $\tan10^{\circ}$ which has $3$ distinct real roots.Now,$\tan10^{\circ}$ has only one value.

So,why am I getting $3$ values and which one value is correct?

Thanks for any help!!

Comment: Can you post how you are solving equation and value of different roots.

Comment: @KanwaljitSingh You can simply plot the graph on Desmos and see where it intersects the $X-Axis$

Comment: It is very common: you have enlarged the set of solutions, that's all. Example $x=2 \implies x^2=4$ but all solutions of the latter equation are not solutions of the former!

Comment: Practically speaking, $\tan(10^{\circ})  = \tan(\pi/18) \approx \pi/18$, so pick the value closest to that.

Comment: 3 values because it is cubic equation

Comment: @Ramanujan Yeah I know that a cubic equation has *atmost* $3$ roots....But $\tan10^{\circ}$ has only one value not $3$....

Comment: $10^{\circ}$ is not the only value $x$ such that $\tan(3x) = \tan(30^{\circ})$ however. For example, I can tell you that your other roots will be $\tan(70^{\circ})$ and $\tan(130^{\circ})$...

Answer (score 5):

$\tan 3x=\tan30\implies 3x=30+n\cdot180°\implies x=10+n\cdot60°$

Comment: I specifically wanted to know where the error lies in my method....

Comment: @tatan This answer explained where the error lies. By solving your equation you are also obtaining $\tan 70°,\tan130°$ as roots.

Answer (score 2):

The cubic equation is
$$f(x)\ =\ \sqrt3x^3-3x^2-3\sqrt3x+1\ =\ 0$$
Now

$f(-2)<0$ and $f(-1)>0$ $\implies$ one of the roots is negative

and

$f(2)<0$ and $f(3)>0$ $\implies$ one of the roots is greater than $1$

But you know that $0<\tan10^\circ<\tan45^\circ=1$ so this is the value you want.

Answer (score 1):

$$-\sqrt3\tan^310+3\tan^210^{\circ}+3\sqrt3\tan10^{\circ}-1=0$$
Can actually be written as **two** equations:
$$\begin{cases}
-\sqrt3x^3+3x+3\sqrt3x-1=0\\
x=\tan10^{\circ}
\end{cases}\tag{1}$$
So we need to find $x$ that satisfies both equations.

The cubic equation has three roots: $2.7475, -1.1918,$ and $0.1763$. From the second equation we know

- $x>0$.
- $x<\tan(30^{\circ})=\frac{\sqrt{3}}{3}=0.5774$.

The only answer that matches these conditions and is the actual answer of the system of equations in $(1)$ is $0.1763$.

Answer (score 1):

You want to know the number $t:=\tan10^\circ$. It so happens that you know $\tan30^\circ={1\over\sqrt{3}}$ and the addition formula for $\tan$. From these facts you conclude that $t$ has to satisfy the equation
$${3t-t^3\over 1-3t^2}={1\over\sqrt{3}}\ .$$
This equation has three real roots $\tau_k$ $(1\leq k\leq 3)$. At this moment all you can say for sure is that
$$t\in\{\tau_1,\tau_2,\tau_3\}\ .$$
But the argument does not work automatically backwards: You **only** have proven that the (one-element) set of solutions to the original problem is a subset of $\{\tau_1,\tau_2,\tau_3\}$. Note that the $\tau_k$s are nothing but the solutions of the last equation in your deduction. This deduction has maybe introduced many extraneous solutions. Why should all three $\tau_k$s be solutions to the original problem? If however, you had a general theory about such problems guaranteeing three values for $\tan10^\circ$ then you would be allowed to accept all three $\tau_k$s without further ado.

Comment: How do you say that $t$ is a subset of the big solution set you obtain.... By my experience I know that if a cubic equation has $3$ roots all the three are solutions... so far,I have known that if we obtain 3 roots of a equation all three are acceptable solutions.... I have never known that the actual solution of an ** equation** can be a subset of all solutions obtained... can you please extend and explain a little more on this point of subset of all solutions....